# How do you translate this to objective C?

Tags: python, objective-c, oop

```
class MyClass():
    def printer(name="abc", description="123")
        print name + description
```

This is python...how can you translate that to objective C?

Comment: What have you tried? SO doesn't write code for you; it answers questions. Come back when you get stuck.

Comment: If you tell what this function does...

Comment: "how can you translate that to objective C?" Here's how: Step 1.  Post it on Stack Overflow.  Step 2.  Reap rewards of having someone else do my homework for me.  Step 3.  Fail final exam because I learned nothing.  Step 4.  Fall back to business school.  Step 5.  Reap rewards of not having to work as a programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will get you started:

```
- (void)printName:(NSString *)name andDescription:(NSString *)description
{
    if (name == nil) name = @"abc";
    if (description == nil) description = @"123";
    NSLog(@"%@%@", name, description);
}
```

Comment: how would you call that function from main?

Comment: If you define it inside a class method, you would do: `[object printName:@"Kevin" andDescription:@"The Great"];`